# How iterate to find if any record in a table exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

New to rails not sure I'm wrapping my head around this issue. So I have db with two tables through sql lite. Bars and reviews. The id of bars is a foreign key on reviews.

```
    create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "picture"
    t.integer "bar_id"
    t.boolean "flagged_innapropriate"
    t.boolean "moderated"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["bar_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_bar_id"
  end

  create_table "bars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "flagged_innapropriate"
    t.string "picture"
    t.boolean "moderated"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

I have a section that is on my navbar, in there it iterates and finds all the bars that have no reviews.

```
    <div class="top-text">
  <p>Be the first to review these bars! </p>
</div>

<div id="norev-container">

  <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
    <% if bar.name? && !bar.flagged_innapropriate && bar.reviews.length == 0 %>

      <div class="bar-container">
        <%= link_to image_tag(bar.picture.thumb.url), %`/bars/#{bar.id}/reviews/new`%>
      </div>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>

</div>

<%= javascript_pack_tag 'norev' %>
```

And that works fine. I also have a navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bar Reviews</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('favicon.ico') %>

</head>

  <body>
  <a href="/">
        <h1 id="title-top">
            Bar Reviews
        </h1>
      </a>
    <header>
      <nav class="navBar">
        <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
        <%= link_to "Bars", bars_path %>
        <%= link_to "No Reviews", bars_norev_path %>
        <%= link_to "About", pages_about_url %>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want the link to the "No Review" page hidden when there are no bars without reviews. But I cannot wrap my head around how I would iterate over the tables to find this out. Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a wicked [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you have there. You don't want to know how to "How iterate to find if any record in a table exists". You want to know "How to conditionally generate a link?"

In your case, just do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bar Reviews</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('favicon.ico') %>

</head>

  <body>
  <a href="/">
        <h1 id="title-top">
            Bar Reviews
        </h1>
      </a>
    <header>
      <nav class="navBar">
        <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
        <%= link_to "Bars", bars_path %>
        <%= link_to("No Reviews", bars_norev_path) if @bars_needing_review.any? %>
        <%= link_to "About", pages_about_url %>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>

</html>
```

Naturally, you'll need to set the `@bars_needing_review` variable somewhere appropriate in your controller (could be in `ApplicationController` - depends). Something, perhaps like:

```
@bars_needing_review = Bar.with_name.not_flagged_as_inappropriate.without_any_reviews
```

This implies that you've set up the `with_name`, `not_flagged_as_inappropriate`, and `without_any_reviews` methods on your `Bar` class, something like:

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord

  class << self 

    def with_name
      where.not(name: nil)
    end

    def not_flagged_as_inappropriate
      where.not(flagged_inappropriate: true)
    end

    def without_any_reviews
      left_joins(:reviews).where(reviews: {id: nil})
    end

  end

end
```

A note here... Someone will come along and say those should be scopes, not class methods. They would not necessarily be wrong. That is a matter of some opinion and you should do what makes you happy. If that sort of things floats your boat, then maybe something like:

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord

  scope :with_name,                     -> { where.not(name: nil) }
  scope :not_flagged_as_inappropriate,  -> { where.not(flagged_inappropriate: true) }
  scope :without_any_reviews,           -> { left_joins(:reviews).where(reviews: {id: nil}) }

end
```

Credit to max's answer for the `left_joins(:reviews).where(reviews: {id: nil})` bit.

Also, this bit:

```
<div id="norev-container">
  <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
    <% if bar.name? && !bar.flagged_innapropriate && bar.reviews.length == 0 %>
      <div class="bar-container">
        <%= link_to image_tag(bar.picture.thumb.url), %`/bars/#{bar.id}/reviews/new`%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

...is really terrible:

1. You shouldn't have that much logic in the view,
2. You've got a N+1 problem
3. You're handcrafting a link!

So, instead, try something like:

```
<div id="norev-container">
  <% @bars_needing_review.each do |bar| %>
      <div class="bar-container">
        <%= link_to new_bar_review_path(bar) do %>
          <%= image_tag(bar.picture.thumb.url) %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Syntax may be a little off. Again, sorry for the rush. You'll still have an N+1 problem b/c of that `bar.picture` call. So, you may need to do something like:

```
@bars_needing_review = Bar.includes(:picture).with_name.not_flagged_as_inappropriate.without_any_reviews
```

Also, you'll need to set up your `routes.rb` to include something like:

```
resources :bars do 
  resources :reviews, shallow: true
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This typically is something you want to do [with a database query](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). Not by iterating across all the records in the table in Ruby.

Getting records with no rows in a join table can be done with a left outer join:

```
@bars = Bar.left_joins(:reviews)
           .where(flagged_innapropriate: false) # make sure you add a default to the column!
           .where.not(name: nil) # smelly - this should be handled by a validation?
           .where(reviews: { id: nil })
```